# Read-only select element

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Readonly SELECT tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/readonly-select-tag)

How do I make a select element read-only? I don't want to make it disabled because I am also posting its value.

Take care.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden input item, and assign the Select value to this hidden item whenever the Select value changes.  You can then disable the select box, and you'll still get the hidden value posted.