# JavaScript blur not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, focus, onfocus

```
<html>
<body>

<select onfocus='blur(this);'>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

In firefox this works fine. In IE8, by clicking repeatedly you can get the options to appear. What gives? Anything else I can do to get the select to be readonly without showing it as disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be onfocus="this.blur()"

but why would you do this? Just disable it. If you need the value, copy it to a hidden field

UPDATE:

```
<script>
function changeSel(idx) {
  var sel = document.forms[0].sel;
  sel.selectedIndex=idx;
  sel.form.selCopy.value=idx;
}
window.onload=function() {
  changeSel(document.forms[0].sel.selectedIndex);
}  
</script>
<form>
<input type="text" name="selCopy" value="not set" />
<select name="sel" size="1" disabled="disabled">
<option>Zero</option>
<option>One</option>
<option selected>Two</option>
<option>Three</option>
<option>Four</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="changeSel(3)" value="Three" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. But same problem in IE8, you can still get the options to display. I am doing this because I am showing a popup when the select is clicked because I do not want the options list appearing below the select. I could not find a way to reposition it.

Comment: @Tim so that means your question is wrong. Instead ask the question about what you want and not how to solve the problem you got when you decided on a specific workaround :)

Comment: @Tim basically it sounds like you do not want a select at all

Comment: What do you suggest I do? But still a legit ? on why this does not behave in IE8.

Comment: I suggest you show us what you want to achieve and we suggest how to do it without trying to break something for the user. A simple text field should be fine. Why have a select if you do not want to show the selections? Anyway, what do you mean by "you can still get the options to display" if you have disabled="disabled" ???

Comment: Why would you do this? Sometimes you need the readonly attribute versus disabled. In HTML5, you can't validate disabled fields, but you can validate readonly fields.

Comment: When would you need to validate something the user cannot update?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to go here:
[HTML form readonly SELECT tag/input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/readonly-select-tag)