# How to enable/disable select tag and post it (even if disabled) with knockout

Tags: post, knockout.js, html-select, disabled-input

I have a complex form with many selects whose state (enabled/disabled) depends on the value of some other controls, so it could happen that these selects are disabled when submitting the form (and the select value is not posted). I need to post the selected value even in the case the user is not allowed to change the select.

I saw some solutions here [HTML form readonly SELECT tag/input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/readonly-select-tag) (mainly the solution is to have an hidden field synchronized with the disabled select).

I am thinking to taking a slightly different approach: I want to use knockout (already used in the project) to display the select only when the data is editable, and display a readonly input (or a div/span) otherwise.

How can I use knockout to simplify this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my viewModel I define the property relative to the state of the select, the property bounded to the select value and a computed observable that "reads" the description of the selected option in the select:

```
AppViewModel: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.SelectVisible = ko.computed(function () {
            return true;  // return true or false depending on your context
        }, self);
        self.Category = ko.observable("");
        self.CategoryText = ko.computed(function () {
            return $("#Category option[value='" + self.Category() + "']").text();
        }, self);
        // other code ...
}
```

In the page I have a select always enabled and a readonly input whose visibility is mutually esclusive and depends on a viewModel property:

```
<select name="Category" id="Category" data-bind="value: Category, visible: SelectVisible">
   <option value="S">Standard</option>
   <option value="N">CatN</option>
   <option value="C">CatC</option>
</select>
<input style="display: none;" type="text" readonly="readonly" data-bind="value: CategoryText, visible: !SelectVisible()"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply disabling the select is enough to prevent it from posting -- you don't have to make it readonly. This is actually pretty straight-forward. With the `attr` binding, you can apply an attribute conditionally. So all you need is an observable that holds a boolean state for the select:

**In your view model**

```
self.DisableSelects = ko.observable(false);
```

**Your select binding**

```
attr: { disabled: DisableSelects }
```

Then, you just set the observable to true when you want any selects bound like that to be disabled:

```
viewModel.DisableSelects(true)
```

Obviously, if you want greater granularity, you just create more observables like this and bind appropriately.

**EDIT**

Your question is not explicit about what you're actually wanting, but I have a feeling that the problem is you actually *do* want the value posted even if it's disabled. On that, I have to agree with the first answer on the linked question: don't rely on the posted value being there at all. Making a field readonly or disabled does *not* prevent the value from being changed. Every modern browser has development tools built-in that let's you change HTML in place (i.e. remove the readonly or disabled flag), and anyone with even a basic knowledge of HTML can pull that off. IF you want a field readonly, then the only safe way to accomplish that is to *completely* disregard the posted value. You can do all sorts of tricks with hidden inputs and such, but that can easily be gotten around as well.

Comment: Yes, I do want the value posted even if it's disabled. I'm sorry that I wasn't not so explicit and will edit the question. I have no security concerns because my application is a data-centric intranet application, but I will pay more attention to the issues that you have highligthed. Thank you!

Comment: Well, even though security may not be a concern, it's always better to treat any application as if it may be compromised, if for no other reason than if you *stop* worrying about it for one app, you might not remember to actually worry about it for the next app that *will* matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could just bind the knockout view model variable "IsDisable" to the select list