# Select disable doesn't pass the value correctly

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Please help me.
I use Codeigniter.

In VIEW i have

```
'<select name="sender[]" style="width:150px" class="chzn-select" disabled='disabled'>
<?php foreach($statments as $statement): ?>
<option value="<? echo $statement->id; ?>" <?php echo ($statement->id==$pris->sender)?"selected='selected'":""; ?>><?php echo $statement->name; ?>'<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If i use "disabled" it passes "sender" as NULL. 
if i remove "disabled" it works fine, but i need not active select.

Answer (score 4):

A `disabled` element does not send its value in the `POST`.

If you want data to be passed but prevent users from editing the field, use `readonly` instead.

**edit:** Apparently, this isn't an option for `<select>` boxes. See [HTML form readonly SELECT tag/input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/readonly-select-tag) for a solution.

http://kreotekdev.wordpress.com/2007/11/08/disabled-vs-readonly-form-fields/

Comment: Thanks. But I solve problem this way. Found at http://stackoverflow.com/  :)
`<script>
        $('select option:not(:selected)').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       });
       </script>`

Comment: I ran into this same issue. The [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) provide a more detailed explanation of the `disabled` attribute's behavior. Additionally, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23428851/3330552) from a different question helped me find a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Would like to point out that the answer above is the best solution so far.

```
$('select option:not(:selected)').each(function(){ $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); });
```

For the reason that, even when it's still disabled, the value still pass to the database without an error.