# Default Value in drop down list not being selected

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down list [ Incident, Question, Problem, Task]. I have written a code when an end user logins in and has a tag called product the default value should be problem. However it does not seem to work. It still gives the user the option to select values from the list.

```
$j(document).ready(function() {  
if(location.pathname == '/requests/new') {
var ct = currentUser.tags;

 if(ct.indexOf("product") >= 0){
 $j(document.getElementById("ticket_fields_75389").value = "Problem"); 
  }
 else {
 $j(document.getElementById("ticket_fields_75389").value = "");
 } 

 }
 })
```

Comment: should it not be like `$j("#ticket_fields_75389").val("Problem"); `

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** This answer is incorrect. I will delete it once I know the OP read my comment.

---

> It still gives the user the option to select values from the list.

Well, of course, setting `value` will only change the initially selected value. If you want "fix" the value of the select element, so that the user cannot change it, you have to make it **read-only**. Lets stick with jQuery (what you have is a weird mix of DOM API and jQuery <sup>†</sup>):

```
$j("#ticket_fields_75389").val("Problem").prop('readonly', true);
```

---

†: Let's have a close look at the line

```
$j(document.getElementById("ticket_fields_75389").value = "Problem");
```

What exactly is happening here? Obviously we have a function call (`$j(...)`) and we pass something to it. This "something" is the result of the expression

```
document.getElementById("ticket_fields_75389").value = "Problem"
```

This finds an element by ID and assigns the string `"Problem"` to the `value` property. This is an *assignment expression*. The result of an assignment expression is the assigned value, i.e. `"Problem"`.

That is the value that is passed to `$j(...)`, so we have `$j("Problem");`. Since `$j` refers to `jQuery`, this would search for all elements with **tag name** `Problem`, which does not exist in HTML. It would also *return* a jQuery object, but you are not doing anything with it.

Hence the wrapping in `$j(...)` is completely unnecessary or even wrong, even though it doesn't throw a syntax or runtime error.

Comment: Hi the reason i used this code is because i am wrting an API in Zendesk. This worked for another drop down list. Here it is not working which is quite strange. I tried the suggestion it is not working.

Comment: Not working how? I can only help you if you describe your problem and your goal precisely.

Comment: Assume that you are an end-user having some kind of problem with a item. We have multiple forms that you can raise a concern. E.g Sales. Since your id is associated with a tag called product and you select the sales form. There are various ticket fields associated with the form. Once such field is Type. Which has the drop down  list as mentioned. Since you have a tag called product the default option should be "problem".

Comment: OK. But you still didn't explain what exactly didn't work. In any case, I noticed that `readonly` has no effect on `select` elements, so that might be what you are referring to. I found this question which explains what to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/readonly-select-tag. I will leave this answer until you read my comment (pls let me know) and then delete it because it clearly doesn't solve the problem.