# Disable double click on SELECT tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to do is to have a read-only Select tag and I found this post here [HTML form readonly SELECT tag/input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/readonly-select-tag). It does works by putting `this.blur()` when it is on focus.

However, when I tried with IE, I still manage to access the list when I double click on the select tag. Is there any way I can disable that on IE?

Thanks.

Comment: Readonly `select`? Why not just have a select with only 1 option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just cover a transparent div above?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="xyz">
  <option disabled>Read Only</option>
  <option>Clickable</option>
  <option>Clickable</option>
  <option>Clickable</option>
</select>
```