# Disable drop down list by Jquery but maintain the value in server side

Tags: jquery, server-side, backend, html-select, javascript

Good day all,

I tried to disable a drop down list by jQuery, and I would like to maintain the value in the drop down list in server side/ back-end although it has been disable.

This is my jQuery code:

```
if('${actionBean.list1.size()}' > 0)
    $('#dropdownA').prop("disabled", true);
```

However, after I disable the drop down, the value become null in my java file :

```
System.out.println("dropdown value is " + getdropdownA());
```

Any idea to maintain the value although I disable the drop down list after user selected on it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Readonly SELECT tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/readonly-select-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled elements do not get submitted with forms (hence the null value), so the easiest way to get around this would be to use a hidden element.

Something like:

```
if('${actionBean.list1.size()}' > 0){
  var dropDown = $('#dropdownA');
  $("myHiddenElement").val(dropDown.val());
  dropDown.prop("disabled", true);
}
```

Then you can check if dropDown has a value on the server and if not, default to myHiddenElement.

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

```
   $('#dropdownA').attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: This has the same effect as `$('#dropdownA').prop("disabled", true);` and presumably won't help here.

Answer (score 0):

try using this to make the dropdown displayed as if it is 'disabled'

```
$(#dropdownA).css({"background-color":"rgb(238, 238, 238)", "pointer-events":"none"}).keydown(false)
```