# Want to access the value of a disabled combobox

Tags: php, html

In my combobox certain condition i disable the combobox.But i want to access the values in the controller.Now i can't get it.Readonly not working

```
<select class="select2" id="branch" name="branch" required="required" onchange="getDept();" <?php if(!empty($detailone)){?> disabled="true" <?php } ?>>
```

Comment: you may use js+ajax or set the box to `readonly="readonly"` and remove the disabled attribute.

Comment: change from `diasbled` to `readonly`: `... readOnly=true ...`

Comment: readonly not working with select tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a solution:

```
<option value="<?php echo $barn['id'];?>"<?php if(!empty($detailone)){ if($bid==$barn['id']){?> selected="selected"<?php }else {?> disabled="disabled" <?php }} ?>>
<?php echo $barn['b_name'];?></option>
```

Here i disable the values except the selected one

Answer (score 6):

you can not get the value of `disabled` fields.you can use `readonly=true` instead of `disabled`. Like in your case :

```
<select class="select2" id="branch" name="branch" required="required" onchange="getDept();" <?php if(!empty($detailone)){?> readonly="true" <?php } ?>>
```

Comment: @Harsha Mahajan read only not support fro select http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/html-form-readonly-select-tag-input

Answer (score 1):

You cant't make is as readonly. Because  not tag does't have any **values** . So you need to try better javascript to overcome this issue.

**Try this**

```
<select id="countries" onfocus="this.defaultIndex=this.selectedIndex;" onchange="this.selectedIndex=this.defaultIndex;">
<option value="1">Country1</option>
<option value="2">Country2</option>
<option value="3">Country3</option>
<option value="4">Country4</option>
<option value="5">Country5</option>
<option value="6">Country6</option>
<option value="7" selected="selected">Country7</option>
<option value="8">Country8</option>
<option value="9">Country9</option>
</select>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/html-form-readonly-select-tag-input)

Comment: Thanks.I got a solution