# how to set select element as readonly ('disabled' doesnt pass select value on server)

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, readonly

When i used any of the following code ,`select` element do looks like disabled,but the select is not pass on the server : Im thinking of the `readonly` to be used, but i dont know or is that will solved the issue. Any help is much appreciated.

```
$('#selectID').prop('disabled',true);

$('#selectID').prop('disabled','disabled');

$('#selectID').attr('disabled',true);

$('#selectID').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: try `readonly` attribute

Comment: how? i dont want that to put taht html.

Comment: $('#selectID').attr('readonly', true)

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML form readonly SELECT tag/input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/html-form-readonly-select-tag-input)

Comment: @monkeyinsight see this, is not working http://jsfiddle.net/59wLyk3n/

Comment: Why do you show a select if you don't want to change the values? I think it is an other solution to show only one item in the select.

Comment: If 'readonly' worked on <select> elements no one would be asking this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To be able to pass the `select`, I just set it back to :

```
  $('#selectID').prop('disabled',false);
```

or

```
  $('#selectID').attr('disabled',false);
```

when passing the request.

Comment: .removeAttr() should be used instead

Comment: If you disable, it is no longer sent in the form, it has to be 'readonly'.

Comment: @PalomitaYañezQuiroz, that's the point above - when the form is submitted, just before it goes out, you manually turn off the "disable" part.

Answer (score 24):

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/html-form-readonly-select-tag-input) - [HTML form readonly SELECT tag/input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/html-form-readonly-select-tag-input)

> You should keep the select element disabled but also add another
> hidden input with the same name and value.
>
> If you reenable your SELECT, you should copy it's value to the hidden
> input in an onchange event.

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9s3osa46/) to demnstrate how to extract the selected value in a disabled select into a hidden field that will be submitted in the form.

```js
$(function() {
  var select_val = $('#sel_test option:selected').val();
  $('#hdn_test').val(select_val);
  $('#output').text('Selected value is: ' + select_val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select disabled="disabled" id="sel_test">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="hdn_test" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

hope that helps.

Comment: can you give me fiddle or exaple on how to used this work around?

Comment: Why not simply close the question as a dup?

Comment: @GalV,is that will pass on server? what value should be pass if i dont disabled the select? see this http://jsfiddle.net/9s3osa46/1/

Comment: it depends, how do you pass the data to the server? is it a <form>? is it AJAX?
usually, when using FORM, you should give the html element a name attribute. when using ajax, you decide what to pass to the server in a dictionary of parameters.

Comment: when you submit a form, every element in the form with the `name` attribute will be sent to server. you need to make sure that only 1 of the elements will hold that name at a single time (start with the name att. on the `select` element, and if it's changed, move the `name` att. to the hidden field)

Comment: Hello @GalV, i dont want the hidden as work around. any other idea?

Answer (score 16):

You can simulate a readonly select box using the CSS [pointer-events property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events):

```
select[readonly]
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

The HTML [tabindex property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) will also prevent it from being selected by keyboard tabbing:

```
<select tabindex="-1">
```

```css
select[readonly]
{
    pointer-events: none;
}


/* irrelevent styling */

*
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*[readonly]
{
  background: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #555;
}

input, select
{
  display:block;
  width: 20rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value="this is a normal text box">
  <input type="text" readonly value="this is a readonly text box">
  <select readonly tabindex="-1">
    <option>This is a readonly select box</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>This is a normal select box</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: You can't use pointer-events: none. That will prevent the element from receiving focus on click. (This is important for an accessibility reason.) Also, using tabIndex to prevent focus is a terrible idea. Blind or visually impaired users will not be able to read the content of the field anymore, or not even notice that the field is there.

Answer (score 11):

without disabling the selected value on submitting..

```
$('#selectID option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true);

If you use Jquery version lesser than 1.7
$('#selectID option:not(:selected)').attr('disabled', true);
```

It works for me..

Comment: Worked perfectly! Can still submit with values, without user being able to change selection. TY!

Comment: This should be the answer. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 6):

To simplify things here's a jQuery plugin that can achieve this goal : https://github.com/haggen/readonly

1. Include readonly.js in your project. (also needs jquery)
2. Replace `.attr('readonly', 'readonly')` with `.readonly()` instead.
   That's it.

   For example, change from `$(".someClass").attr('readonly', 'readonly');`
           to `$(".someClass").readonly();`.