# Rails form_for select, invalid selected when disabled: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can you guys help me with my little problem? this is my select tag:

`<%= f.select :department_id, options_for_select(Department.in_order.map {|d| [d.name, d.id]}, obj.department_id), { prompt: true }, class: 'form-control input-sm', disabled: lambda {action_name == 'revise'} %>`

if `disabled: true` is set, I get "Department is invalid" error on my validation. When not set, everything is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that HTML fields when `disabled` are not submitted with the form. What you need is `readonly`. Readonly gives you the same functionality as disabled but is still submitted with the form.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Comment: Thanks for the info and I will mark that as an answer. BTW, I read the documentation in apidock, and readonly attribute is not available for select tag. Even in raw html there's no readonly attribute. Perhaps, I should change my form's flow.

Comment: Here's another StackOverflow question that may help with that problem, http://stackoverflow.com/q/368813/575985. They suggest keeping the select disabled but having a hidden input with the same name and value so that it will be passed with the form.

Comment: :D Thanks a lot! I will try re-enabling select tag on submit.