# Way to lock a select element after a radio button is selected in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select drop down filled with options and then I have two radios like so...

```
<form>
  <select id="drop_down">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
  </select>

  <div id="radios">
    <input type="radio" value="blue" id="blue" name="radio_option">Blue</input>
    <input type="radio" value="green" id="green" name="radio_option">Green</input>
  </div>
</form>
```

My goal is that once a user makes a selection in the drop down and then selects a radio button... then the select drop down will (for lack of a better term) "lock up", preventing the user from going back and changing their drop down selection.

I know there's a way in jQuery to accomplish this... however I have not been able to find a way...

This is my jQuery so far (it's wrong)... I am not sure what the event should be after the `$('#drop_down')`....

```
$('#radios').change(function(){
  $('#drop_down').removeProp(select);
});
```

I realize this may be a simple solution... I'm just not finding the right event handler in the jQuery Docs...

Comment: Note that IDs **must be unique**. You are recycling the `blue` ID for both radio buttons.

Comment: Thanks @Terry for catching that. I should have been more observant when copying and pasting...

Comment: Also note that the `</input>` tag is invalid. It is a self closing element. If you want to associate a text with an input, use the `<label>` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the attribute `disabled` to the `select` element upon the radio input changing states. And remove the `disabled` attribut upon form submission, allowing the input to be sent.

```js
$('#radios input').change(function(){
  $('#drop_down').prop('disabled', true);
});

$('form').on('submit', function() {
    $(this).find('#drop_down').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="post">

    <select id="drop_down">
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
      <option value="4">Four</option>
    </select>
    
    <div id="radios">
      <input type="radio" value="blue" id="blue" name="radio_option">Blue</input>
      <input type="radio" value="green" id="blue" name="radio_option">Green</input>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Actually using `.prop('disabled', true)` would be sufficient. These attributes (e.g. `readonly`, `disabled`) are binary, therefore do not require any value ;)

Comment: Perfect! This is just what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

You can set the button to be disabled, and update a hidden field to use the selected option, so that it also passes when you post the form.

**EDIT (adding the code)**

The HTML (notice the last input still within the form):

```
<select id="drop_down">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
<form id="radios">
  <input type="radio" value="blue" id="blue" name="radio_option" class="radios">Blue</input>
  <input type="radio" value="green" id="green" name="radio_option" class="radios">Green</input>
  <input type="hidden" id="myvalue" name="radio_option" />
</form>
```

The jQuery code (notice I'm giving a class to the radios above, and am using that in js, so that when I do the disabling, the hidden input doesn't get disabled):

```
$('.radios').change(function() {
  $(this).attr('disabled', true);
  $('#myvalue').val($(this).val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the select's attribute: `disabled="disabled"`

```js
alert($('select').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drop_down" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
<select>
```

**EDIT**

As MarcB points out, if you need to get the value of the `disabled` select element, you can do so explicitly when the form is submitted.

Comment: this will work, but will also prevent the select's value from being submitted - disabled elements are not submitted with the rest of a form.

Comment: OP is trying to prevent use of a `select`

Comment: @MarcB Well, the select isn't part of the form anyway.  It's not clear to me what the end intent is there.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your code, where you recycled the ID `blue` for both radio buttons. I am not sure if this is an intended feature or a typo, but you will need to rectify it as IDs are supposed to be unique in a document. In addition, `<input />` is a self closing element, so the `</input>` tag is invalid. Instead, use `<label for="(id)">`.

`.removeProp()` is likely not a good idea (so is `.removeAttr()`) because attributes or properties that have been removed cannot be added back later. Instead, use `.prop('...', false)` to "unset" a property. In your case, we want to disable the `<select>` element, and this is done by using `.prop('disabled', true)`. However, since **disabled elements will not have their values submitted**, you will need to copy the final value of the select element into a hidden element, as per strategy [mentioned in an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/html-form-readonly-select-tag-input).

```js
$(function() {
    $('#radios').change(function(){
        $('#drop_down')
        .prop('disabled', true)
        .next()
        .val($('#drop_down').val());
        
        console.log($('#drop_down_final').val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drop_down">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="drop_down_final" />
<form id="radios">
    <input type="radio" value="blue" id="blue" name="radio_option" /><label for="blue">Blue</label>
    <input type="radio" value="green" id="green" name="radio_option" /><label for="green">Green</label>
</form>
```