# HTML make <option> invalid

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following piece of code in a contact form for a site I am designing:

```
<select id="Category" name="Category">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" disabled>Category</option>
    <option value="1">General Info</option>
    <option value="2">Booking</option>
    <option value="3">Auditions</option>
</select>
```

I would like set the menu such that the user cannot leave `category` as the selected option. Is there any way to do this with HTML? If not, how would I do it with JavaScript?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the user click on any option, he can´t  return the first one back. But he can submit form without change, then you need to validate via JS.

It's quite simple,

```
function validate() {
    var select = document.getElementById('Category');
    return !select.value == 0;
}
```

And the form in HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()">...</form>
```

Comment: I would use `!select.selectedIndex === 0`

Comment: How does the precedence work on that suggestion? Did you check before posting that thought bubble? Does a boolean value ever "triple equal" `0`?  Have a look at `let val = 0; !val === 0;` then `let val = 1; !val === 0;` ...hmm.

Answer (score 40):

According to the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element),

> **Constraint validation**: If the element has its [`required`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-select-required) attribute specified, and either none of the [`option`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) elements in
>   the [`select`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element) element's [list of options](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-select-option-list) have their
>   [selectedness](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-option-selectedness) set to true, or the only [`option`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) element in
>   the [`select`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element) element's [list of options](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-select-option-list) with its
>   [selectedness](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-option-selectedness) set to true is the [placeholder label option](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#placeholder-label-option),
>   then the element is [suffering from being missing](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#suffering-from-being-missing).
>
> If a [`select`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element) element has a [`required`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-select-required) attribute
>   specified, does not have a [`multiple`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-select-multiple) attribute specified, and
>   has a [display size](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-select-size) of 1; and if the [value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-option-value) of the first
>   [`option`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) element in the [`select`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element) element's [list of
>   options](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-select-option-list) (if any) is the empty string, and that [`option`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element)
>   element's parent node is the [`select`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element) element (and not an
>   [`optgroup`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-optgroup-element) element), then that [`option`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) is the select
>   element's **placeholder label option**.

Therefore, you can use

```html
<select id="Category" name="Category" required>
  <option value="" selected disabled>Category</option>
  <option value="1">General Info</option>
  <option value="2">Booking</option>
  <option value="3">Auditions</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Will disabling select work for you?

```
<select id="Category" name="Category" disabled>
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Category</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Or maybe disabling all but selected option will work for you (as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23428851/882073)

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, you would simply remove the `selected` attribute from disabled options on the server side when generating the HTML document to begin with.

Otherwise, if you are using JQuery, this can be done fairly easily with:

```
$('#Category').find('option:not([disabled])').first().prop('selected', true);
```

Add this to your `ondomready` event handler. This will force the first non-disabled option to be selected for this `select` element regardless of its options' `selected` attributes. The disadvantage of this method is that it will prevent the `selected` attribute from being able to be used at all with this `select` element.

On the other hand, if you are trying to create category headers within a `select` element, you should consider using an `optgroup` element instead, since that is the correct semantic markup for this:

```
<select id="Category" name="Category">
    <optgroup label="Category">
        <option value="1">General Info</option>
        <option value="2">Booking</option>
        <option value="3">Auditions</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```