# How to create readonly select box but I will post that value?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to readonly select box. But I post value from that element. When I disabled it then select box can't post value.

```
<select name="office_name" id="office_name" readonly>
    <option value="">----Select Office----</option> 
    <option value="1">Bengli</option>   
    <option value="2">English</option>  
</select>
```

Readonly does not work but disabled work.
But I need readonly not disabled.
Is it Possible?

Comment: readonly on select option?

Comment: What's the point of a readonly select? Just put the value in a readonly textbox if the user is unable to change it.

Comment: one option will selected and select box readonly....

Comment: user can't change option but selected value will be post

Comment: @SalmanQuader Having `readonly` is fine right? User cannot click it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML form readonly SELECT tag/input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/html-form-readonly-select-tag-input)

Answer (score 1):

What about avoiding any mousedwon/keydown event:

```
$('#office_name').on('mousedown keydown', function(){ 
  return !$(this).hasClass('readonly');
});
```

And then, just toggle `readonly` class to able or disable user selection.

See [-jsFiddle-](https://jsfiddle.net/szcsewu5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

Just don't disable option which you want to post else disable all options

So 2 value will be posted into PHP now.

```html
<select>
  <option disabled="disabled">1</option>
  <option selected="selected">2</option> <!-- just dont disable option which you want to post else disable all options-->
  <option disabled="disabled">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I need readonly not disabled
if i use disabled then this value of tag won't be post

Comment: user can't see dropdown list enabled or disabled

Comment: I used <code>$("#office_name option:not(selected)").attr('disabled',true);</code>code but i want to disabled dropdown but I post value