# Select and option predefined text

Tags: html

Suddenly I am in doubt, how do you have a predefined text in a form, but the text cannot be chosen. More like a text there is defining the subject on the form.

I have this short form here.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="sr-only" for="cars">H</label>
  <select id="cars" name="cars" class="form-control"  required>
     <option>Cars</option>
     <option>Lamborghini</option>
     <option>Volvo</option>
     <option>Toyota</option>
     <option>Chervolet</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

So the main point is that cars should be in the form field but we should not be able to choose it. Any one knows how to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/html-form-readonly-select-tag-input aaaaaand http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<option disabled>Cars</option>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-disabled

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#Attributes