# jQuery .prop('disabled', true) ignores .val('myval')

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery v1.4.4. I have a very simple form:

```
<select class="myselect" name="myselect">
<option value="-1" selected="selected">N/Av</option>
<option value="-2">N/Ap</option>
<option value="0">Available</option>
</select>
```

What I want to achieve is set the value to `0` (`Available`) and disable the select. So I do the following:

```
$('.myselect').val('0');
$('.myselect').prop('disabled', true);
```

The output is correct: `Available` is being selected and the select is disabled. When I submit the form however, the value of `$_POST['myselect']` is `-1`. When I only use...

```
$('.myselect').val('0');
```

... the value of `$_POST['myselect']` is `0` as expected.

So my question: is there a way to disable `myselect` and still set the value?

Comment: You are missing `'`, but maybe that is not the issue. Maybe is a typo when you wrote the question?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it was indeed a typo when writing the question.

Comment: Ok. However the behaviour doesn't match what you're doing. If the element is disabled its value will not be sent in the form POST. Are you sure you only have one control with that name?

Comment: *"I'm using jQuery v1.4.4."* ***Why?*** It's been out of date for **years**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I submit the form however, the value of `$_POST['myselect']` is `-1`.
>
> ...
>
> So my question: is there a way to disable myselect and still set the value?

That's what that code would do, but:

Disabled fields [aren't included in form submissions](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set)*, so if you're getting `-1` from `$_POST['myselect']`, it's coming from somewhere else — the browser won't have sent anything for `myselect` at all (unless you have another `name="myselect"` field you haven't shown).

If you want the field included in the form, don't disable it. Unfortunately, `select` elements don't support `readonly`, so you'll have to either remove the other options or use script to prevent the user from selecting them.

**See also** [Himanshu Tyagi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42484715/157247) pointing out that you're using an API call that isn't in jQuery v1.4.4.

---

* Relevant quote from the spec:

> 1. Let controls be a list of all the submittable elements whose form owner is form, in tree order.
> 2. Let the form data set be a list of name-value-type tuples, initially empty.
> 3. Loop: For each element field in controls, in tree order, run the following substeps:
>
>    If any of the following conditions are met, then **skip these substeps for this element**:
>
>    - The field element has a datalist element ancestor.
>    - **The field element is disabled.**
>    - ...

*(my emphasis)*

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that disabled fields aren't included in form submissions. Since the select tag doesn't support `readonly`, I found my answer in this Q: [HTML form readonly SELECT tag/input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/html-form-readonly-select-tag-input).

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

`.prop` is added since 1.6 and you are using 1.4, see the error log in the code

```js
$('.myselect').val('0');
$('.myselect').prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="myselect" name="myselect">
<option value="-1" selected="selected">N/Av</option>
<option value="-2">N/Ap</option>
<option value="0">Available</option>
</select>
```

If you keep using jQuery 1.4.4, you need to use `attr` instead of `prop`:

```js
$('.myselect').val('0');
$('.myselect').attr('disabled', "disabled");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="myselect" name="myselect">
<option value="-1" selected="selected">N/Av</option>
<option value="-2">N/Ap</option>
<option value="0">Available</option>
</select>
```

> Attributes vs. Properties
>
> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in
>   specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes
>   took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
>   which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop()
>   method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
>   .attr() retrieves attributes.