# Readonly SELECT field

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, forms

In my form I have couple of 'select' fields, among others. Now, when I update form, I need to make some fields readonly. Since I can't disable fields because then I'll get no return value, I need to find a way how can I make 'Select' fields readonly. My idea is to somehow change field type to input/text, and then make that field readonly. Is that possible? Or is there a better way?

What I use on text fields:

```
document.getElementById('id_rn_number').readOnly = true;
```

And I can't use (on any field type):

```
document.getElementById('id_report_division').disabled = true;
```

Comment: use <select disabled>option values...</select>

Comment: Check this [related (and popular) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/html-form-readonly-select-tag-input).